# How to simulate fetch() with local JSON on a Collection or Model?

Tags: parsing, backbone.js, model, fetch, backbone.js-collections

I'm new to Backbone, and trying to set up my Models, and Collections nested within, using a local JSON file for testing. I currently have something like this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    coll: null,
    initialize: function (attributes, options) {
        this.setData(attributes);
    },
    setData: function (data) {
        this.set("key1", data.key1);
        this.set("key2", data.key2);

        var coll = this.coll ? this.coll.reset(data.collData) : new MyCollection(data.collData);
        this.set("coll", coll);
    }
});
// ...
var myModel = new Model(jsonLoadedFromLocalFile);
```

However, my understanding is that once my server is ready to return data, I'll just use `Model.fetch()` and `Collection.fetch()`, and that those will call `Model.parse()` and `Collection.parse()`, and that `parse()` is the proper place to parse data (as opposed to my seemingly-too-manual `setData()`).

What's the preferred way to load in dummy data for testing Models with nested Collections?

Comment: Why not set up a web server and use the `url` properties?

Comment: @muistooshort please tell me more. Seemed simplest to load a local JSON file when I started, but as I said I'm new to Backbone and may be barking up the wrong tree. Not familiar with the "url properties" though I'll research now...

Comment: you can pass path to your local json file in URL attribute of `model` and `collection`. here take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431673/load-data-into-a-backbone-collection-from-json-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        key1: "",
        key2: "",
        coll: null
    },
    initialize: function (attributes, options) {
        this.fetch({ url: attributes.url });
    },
    parse: function (response) {
        this.set("key1", response.key1);
        this.set("key2", response.key2);

        var coll = this.coll ? this.coll.reset(response.collData) : new MyCollection(response.collData);
        this.set("coll", coll);
    }
});
// ...
var myModel = new Model({ url: localJsonURL });
```

Thanks @muneebShabbir.