# Consuming RESTful Cakephp services in Backbonejs

Tags: json, rest, cakephp, backbone.js

Cakephp's RESTful services are available in URLs of format "URL.format" for eg: "/recipes.json" or "/recipes/123.json". 
Where as Backbone JS's Models or Collections use a format of "URL" to access RESTful services. for eg: "/recipes" or "/recipes/123"
How can we configure Backbone Models or Collections to use Cakephp's RESTful services?

Comment: what about change Backbone url to  ``"/recipes.json"``  , here is some answers `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431673/load-data-into-a-backbone-collection-from-json-file

Comment: @Salines when the url is "/recipes.json", to retrieve a particular recipe of id: 123, then the url will formed as "/recipes.json/123". What cakephp need here is "/recipes/123.json"

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Model with its sync method updated as shown below

```
var ParentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: function( method, model, options ) {
        options.url = model.url() + '.json';
        return Backbone.sync( method, model, options );
    }
});
```

Now this model "ParentModel" is inherited in other models. That being said when the sync/fetch/save is called from the sub models, the url is correctly appended with the format string.

I welcome other solutions too. Please feel free to provide your solutions or suggest improvements to mine.

Comment: Overriding `sync` is a bit overkill for what you're trying to do, I think.  Backbone has a well-structured way to describe what end point you want to talk to by overriding the `url()` and/or `urlRoot()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `Backbone.sync` and friends might seem like a reasonable solution, but it then means you need to support the read/write/delete use cases yourself.  For your use case, I'd suggest overriding `url()` and `urlRoot()` method to provide the logic you'd like.  It's probably simplest to use the base method & then add the '.json':

```
var FooModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
          var url = Backbone.Model.prototype.url.call(this);
          return url + '.json';
    },

    urlRoot: function() {
        return '/foo';
    }
});
```

For a Collection, you can provide the URL directly:

```
var FooCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:  FooModel,
    url: function() {
        return '/foo.json';
    }
});
```

This allows you to both use the Model outside of a collection, such as:

```
var model = new FooModel({ id: 50, name: 'foo50'});
model.url();  // <<=== returns '/foo/50.json'
```

It also allows you to use the Collection to manage models too, such as:

```
var collection = new FooCollection([ { id: 30, name: 'foo30' } ]);
collection.url();  // <<=== returns '/foo.json'

var foo30 = collection.get(30);
foo30.url();  // <<=== returns '/foo/30.json'
```

Comment: this method will work, if the sync/fetch is called at the model. How can I use this approach for a collection? Because for a  collection, the url attribute must specify/return the actual url right?

Comment: Updated the sample code to better illustrate how to use it with the Collection; apologies for not seeing that detail in the original question!