# Populating a BackboneJS model with response from an API endpoint

Tags: json, angularjs, backbone.js

I'm new to BackboneJS but I'm doing my best to learn it. I'm more familiar with AngularJS so I have some confusion in BackboneJS but would definitely want to become an expert BackboneJS developer too.

Back at my previous job, I was the frontend dev and I would work with the Java dev guy. We would have a meeting about how the JSON response would look like. Basically, I'll make a REST call(either with Restangular or $http) to one of their endpoints and I'll get a response. The JSON response will be assigned to a scope variable such as $scope.bookCollection. In my template, I'll just use ng-repeat to display it.

Now with BackboneJS, I'd like to do it properly. I read today that a BackboneJS Model is a container. What I'd like to happen is that after making a fetch(), I want the JSON response to be put in the Model that I defined. How is that done?

I found an example jsfiddle but I think it's a very bad example. I can't find something that is helpful right now, something with a good fetched data.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min',
        underscore: 'http://underscorejs.org/underscore',
        backbone: 'http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min'
    },
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },

        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        }
    }
});
require([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/echo/json/',
        defaults: {
            name: '',
            email: ''
        }
    });
    var userDetails = {
        name: 'Nelio',
        email: 'nelio@angelfire.com'
    };
    var user = new UserModel(userDetails);

    user.fetch({
        success: function (user) {
            console.log(user.toJSON());
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/20qbco46/

Comment: Looks like you've created a model, you're calling the fetch method... model will be updated with the data returned from the service... Why do you think this example is bad..? Do you have a specific problem..?

Comment: I am thinking it's not a good example because I don't see the code that will assign the returned values to the properties of the model. I was hoping to see this.name = response.name. However, you said that model will be updated. How will that happen? Will BackboneJS automatically do it for us?

Comment: Yes `backbone.js` does that internally for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the JSON response to be put in the Model that I defined. How is
>   that done?

If you are trying to render the data from you model, you will use a `view` for this:

First, create a [**view**](http://backbonejs.org/#View) to render your data:

```
// Create a new view class which will render you model
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Use underscores templating
    template: _.template('<strong><%= title %></strong> - <%= author %>'),
    initialize: function() {
        // Render the view on initialization
        this.render();
        // Update the view when the model is changed
        this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        // Render your model data using your template
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

**See also**: [**`template`**](http://underscorejs.org/#template) and [**`toJSON`**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) as well as [**`$el`**](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el)

---

Next, create a [**Model**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model):

```
// Create a model class
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/echo/json/',
    defaults: {
        title : '',
        author: ''
    },
});
```

Your model will hold the data fetched from the `url` / `urlRoot`

You can use [**`set`**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) if you are trying to add new attributes to your model.

You can use [**`get`**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get) to grab attributes from your model.

**See also** - [**`save`**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) and [**`destroy`**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy).

---

Then, instantiate your model:

```
// Some dummy data
var instance = {
    title: 'learn Backbone JS',
    author: 'Bobby Longsocks',
};

// Instansite your model
var model = new Book(instance);
```

And finally, [**fetch**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) your model data and create a new instance of you view:

```
// Fetch your model
model.fetch({
    success: function(book) {
        // Instansite your view, passing in your model
        var view = new BookView({model: book, el: $('body')});
    }
});
```

Here is an [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kwgge85L/6/) you can fiddle with.

**And some further reading**: [Annotated Source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll play with it!

Comment: Ok, after playing it so many times, I think it's not the one I was looking for. What I was really looking for was similar to making a GET from a url endpoint which returns a json object. However, can fetch() retrieve from a .json file so we can simulate a real GET method request?

Comment: Yes, `fetch` can retrieve from a Json file - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431673/load-data-into-a-backbone-collection-from-json-file#11827616). You can use `fetch` very similarly to how you would use `ajax` (`fetch` eventually does an Ajax call anyway).  Also - have a look at [Backbone's `emulateHTTP`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP)

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful!

Comment: I got it working. :) However, I need to fix the model's default. Not sure why it's being created outside of the array and not within the retrieved array. http://plnkr.co/edit/cuXQfk8F5R0qS4hS7T0N?p=preview Basically, I wanted each item in the array to also have the other 2 properties(email and author)

Comment: It's fixed after I added parse function in collection definition